# Get bytes from the Int returned from socket intputStream read()

Tags: java, sockets, byte

I have an InputStream and I want to read each char until I find a comma "," from a socket.

Heres my code

```
private static Packet readPacket(InputStream is) throws Exception
{
    int ch;
    Packet p = new Packet();

    String type = "";
    while((ch = is.read()) != 44) //44 is the "," in ISO-8859-1 codification
    {
        if(ch == -1)
            throw new IOException("EOF");
        type += new String(ch, "ISO-8859-1"); //<----DOES NOT COMPILE
    }
    ...
}
```

String constructor does not receive an int, only an array of bytes. I read the documentation and the it says

**read(): 
Reads the next byte of data from the input stream.**

How can I convert this int to byte then ? Is it using only the less significant bits (8 bits) of all 32 bits of the int ?

Since Im working with Java, I want to keep it full plataform compatible (little endian vs big endian, etc...) Whats the best approach here and why ?

PS: I dont want to use any ready-to-use classes like DataInputStream, etc....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The String constructor takes a char[] (an array)

```
type += new String(new byte[] { (byte) ch }, "ISO-8859-1");
```

Btw. it would be more elegant to use a *StringBuilder* for type and make use of its append-methods. Its faster and also shows the intend better:

```
private static Packet readPacket(InputStream is) throws Exception {
    int ch;
    Packet p = new Packet();

    StringBuilder type = new StringBuilder();
    while((ch = is.read()) != 44) {
        if(ch == -1)
            throw new IOException("EOF");
        // NOTE: conversion from byte to char here is iffy, this works for ISO8859-1/US-ASCII
        // but fails horribly for UTF etc.
        type.append((char) ch);
    }
    String data = type.toString();
    ...
}
```

Also, to make it more flexible (e.g. work with other character encodings), your method would better take an InputStreamReader that handles the conversion from bytes to characters for you (take look at InputStreamReader(InputStream, Charset) constructor's javadoc).

Comment: You cannot do this. There is no String constructor that takes a `char` array and a character set. A `char` array holds unencoded unicode values already. It is nonsense to specify it with an encoding type.

Comment: You're right, was thinking of String(byte[])... fixed, thanks for noting.

Comment: +1, The first bit is a workable solution now. It is worth noting that this only works for single byte encodings (which includes ISO-8859-1). The second example with `StringBuilder` is more problematic, and I would never cast a byte directly to a `char`. The second example requires a single byte encoding that *also* has byte values that directly coincide with code points.

Answer (score 2):

For this can use an [`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html), which can read encoded character data from a raw byte stream:

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is, "ISO-8859-1");
```

You may now use `reader.read()`, which will consume the correct number of bytes from `is`, decode as ISO-8859-1, and return a Unicode code point that *can* be correctly cast to a `char`.

*Edit: Responding to comment about not using any "ready-to-use" classes:*

I don't know if `InputStreamReader` counts. If it does, check out Durandal's answer, which is sufficient for certain single byte encodings (like US-ASCII, arguable, or ISO-8859-1).

For multibyte encodings, if you do not want to use any other classes, you would first buffer all data into a `byte[]` array, then construct a `String` from that.

*Edit: Responding to a related question in the comments on Abhishek's answer.*

**Q:**

> *Abhishek wrote*: Can you please enlighten me a little more? i have tried casting integer ASCII to character..it has worked..can you kindly tell where did i go wrong?

**A:**

You didn't go "wrong", per se. The reason ASCII works is the same reason that Brian pointed out that ISO-8859-1 works. US-ASCII is a single byte encoding, and bytes 0x00-0x7f have the same value as their corresponding Unicode code points. So a cast to char is conceptually incorrect, but in practice, since the values are the same, it works. Same with ISO-8859-1; bytes 0x00-0xff have the same value as their corresponding code points in that encoding. A cast to char would not work in e.g. IBM01141 (a single byte encoding but with different values).

And, of course, a single byte to char cast would not work for multibyte encodings like UTF-16, as more than one input byte must be read (a variable number, in fact) to determine the correct value of a corresponding char.

Comment: @Abhishek Then he should go with Durandal's answer.

Comment: @Abhishek Not wanting to use the right tool for the job ... generally isn't a good idea. This really is the correct answer. Not understanding character sets and how Java deals with them is *really bad* when talking about trying to write network code. (+1)

Comment: @JasonC I know I'm being nitpicky but ... it'd work with UTF-8 as long as you were only using US-ASCII (7-bit) chars. UTF-8 maps U+0000 to U+007F directly as single bytes (basically to be backward compatible with 7-bit ASCII). This is actually what will trip up many a novice developer as it *appears* to work ... until someone throws a `å` at you :-D

Comment: And of course ... once you get past two-byte sequences, you're hosed in Java if you try to use `char` at all. (No really, I *don't* have a personal vendetta when it comes to Java and character encoding :-D )

Comment: I can't win. Anyways, proper handling of character data *does* require nits to be picked. I've edited my example to UTF-16 (although it would actually "work" for a *single* UTF-16LE character <= 255).

Comment: Character encoding is teh devil. I know what they were trying to do in Java, and I can appreciate it ... but `char` as a 16-bit int holding UTF16 is just frigging evil IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: Try replacing :

```
  type += new String(ch, "ISO-8859-1");
```

by

```
  type+=(char)ch;
```

This can be done if you receive the ASCII value of the char.Code converts ASCII in to char by casting.

Its better to avoid lengthy code and this would work just fine. The read() function works in many ways:

One way is: `int= inpstr.read();`

Second `inpstr.read(byte)`
So its up to you which method you wanna use.. both have different purpose..

Comment: @JasonC In this case it would be fine. ISO-8859-1 is the first block of Unicode and *is* equal.

Comment: @BrianRoach Totally correct, but I presume that the person who wrote this answer did not *know* that, and I *definitely* do not want the OP to get the idea that a cast to `char` is generally acceptable (and run into trouble with other encoding schemes in other situations).

Comment: Can you please enlighten me a little more? i have tried casting integer ASCII to character..it has worked..can you kindly tell where did i go wrong?

Comment: @Abhishek You didn't go "wrong", per se. The reason ASCII works is the same reason that Brian pointed out that ISO-8859-1 works. US-ASCII is a single byte encoding, and bytes 0x00-0x7f have the same value as their corresponding Unicode code points. So a cast to `char` is conceptually incorrect, but in practice, since the values are the same, it works. Same with ISO-8859-1; bytes 0x00-0xff have the same value as their corresponding code points in that encoding. A cast to `char` would *not* work in e.g. IBM01141 (a single byte encoding but with different values).

Comment: And, of course, a single byte to `char` cast would not work for multibyte encodings like UTF-8, as more than one input byte must be read (a variable number, in fact) to determine the correct value of a corresponding `char`.

Comment: Brian pointed out in another comment that UTF-16 is a better example, as UTF-8 also uses single byte equivalent values <= 0xff. I think the fundamental reason for a lot of confusion is that a huge number of common character sets are supersets of US-ASCII, to aid compatibility, so more often than not you'll observe behavior that *appears* to be correct -- until you don't. Then you cry and wish the HTTP server would have just set the right encoding in its response in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
type += new String(String.valueOf(ch).getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
```